# Is it secure set crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled to true

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

I'm trying to consume a `WCF` service by using `JQuery` but I'm confused. 
I have found many sites telling me to use `JSONP` to workaround same-origin policy and than to set  `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` to true.

Is it secure to set `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` to true?

Is there another way to consume the `WCF` service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cross Domain Policy is there to prevent service not designed for it to be used wrongly.

You can use JSONP only with the GET verb.

If the WCF service is well implemented, you shouldn't be able to update the database with a GET but only with POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE verbs.

1. If you can use JSONP do it, it is simple and easy: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/
2. To be able to use the WCF service with CORS, the WCF service must implement it so yes it is safe to use crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled to true.

You probably want to have a look at: http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery